# Understanding /var/log/messages entries

Tags: linux, logs, d-bus

192.168.25.1 = router

192.168.10.1 = gateway/modem

192.168.25.144 = this pc (which is 'linuxpc' running fedora 17)

What happened during these log entry events below? Specifically what do the last two log entries mean.

```
Oct 10 13:24:22 linuxpc dhclient[5779]: DHCPREQUEST on p14p1 to 192.168.25.1 port 67 (xid=0x466a6633)
Oct 10 13:24:22 linuxpc dhclient[5779]: DHCPACK from 192.168.25.1 (xid=0x466a6633)
Oct 10 13:24:22 linuxpc dhclient[5779]: bound to 192.168.25.144 -- renewal in 32701 seconds.
Oct 10 13:24:22 linuxpc NetworkManager[846]: <info> (p14p1): DHCPv4 state changed renew -> renew
Oct 10 13:24:22 linuxpc NetworkManager[846]: <info>   address 192.168.25.144
Oct 10 13:24:22 linuxpc NetworkManager[846]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
Oct 10 13:24:22 linuxpc NetworkManager[846]: <info>   gateway 192.168.25.1
Oct 10 13:24:22 linuxpc NetworkManager[846]: <info>   hostname 'linuxpc'
Oct 10 13:24:22 linuxpc NetworkManager[846]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.10.1'
Oct 10 13:24:22 linuxpc dbus[910]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Oct 10 13:24:22 linuxpc dbus-daemon[910]: dbus[910]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using     servicehelper)
Oct 10 13:24:22 linuxpc dbus-daemon[910]: dbus[910]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Oct 10 13:24:22 linuxpc dbus[910]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Oct 10 13:30:29 linuxpc dbus-daemon[910]: dbus[910]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.2" (uid=0 pid=865 comm="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.36" (uid=1000 pid=1182 comm="gnome-session ")
Oct 10 13:30:29 linuxpc dbus[910]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.2" (uid=0 pid=865 comm="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.36" (uid=1000 pid=1182 comm="gnome-session ")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First 3 lines are messages from `dhclient` which:

1. sent a DHCP request to the router
2. received DHCP lease
3. set up the interface

next 6 lines are from the NetworkManager, which basically restates the above in more detail reason probably is, that the `dhclient` instance was spawned by NM (rather silly if you ask me, but that's NetworkManager)

Last 6 lines are from the D-Bus daemon. First 4 of these are the imprint of successful activation of the `nm_dispatcher` service (`nm` stands for NetworkManager again) service, which activates services on connection to network.

The 2 remaining lines are (to the best of my understanding) log of rejected message from systemd's `logind` to the GNOME session manager. I don't speak D-Bus and systemd enough to even guess what could have triggered these, but judging my the [man page](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-logind.service.html), *I would expect* it to be either another login/VT switch or "Device access management for users". It would certainly help if you knew what happened around that time.

Comment: Thank you, can you elaborate a bit more on the last two logind entries, are they a failed login attempt?

Comment: See updated answer, but I'm afraid it's not going to help you much - my knowledge of systemd is ~0.